# Build rpm with a lot of files

Tags: linux, unix, rpm

I want to deliver an rpm but the number of files to be delivered is very big.
Do I have to specify each file in the spec under `%files` section or can I just define the top level folder so that they can be inluded recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the top-level folder, all its files will be included as well. If you don't want the rpm to own the top-level folder, you can also use `top-level-folder/*`

Comment: So `*` signifies all the files under `top-level-folder`?

Comment: @Jim yes, without including the top folder itself.